# I am not able to set series color in treemap chart using aspose cells api for java

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-cells

i am trying to set series color in treemap using aspose api in java.

```
series.getArea().getFillFormat().setFillType(FillType.SOLID);
series.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getBlack());
```

**My problem:**

I am not able to set series color in treemap chart using aspose cells api for java

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and it will work fine with other charts like **Column** chart but we are afraid, Aspose.Cells do not support **Tree Map** chart at the moment. Tree Map is Microsoft Excel 2016 chart. We are working to support Excel 2016 charts but it might take good amount of time (in months) because of its complexity.

We have also logged your issue as

- **CELLSJAVA-42585** - Set Series Color in TreeMap using Aspose.Cells API

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose